# Python Popen - command line application not working

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess, popen

I am trying to run the below command line application in python, but now getting anywhere. This works perfectly via Terminal on OSX:

```
/JS/ChannelAssign5+1stereo.app/Contents/MacOS/ChannelAssign5+1stereo "/Volumes/GRAID/_PREVIEWS/MASTER copy.mov"
```

When I try to run the same this via `subprocess.Popen` the command line application opens but does not run the file MASTER copy.mov.

```
    command = ['./JS/ChannelAssign5+1stereo.app/Contents/MacOS/ChannelAssign5+1stereo', '%s' % '/Volumes/GRAID/_PREVIEWS/MASTER copy.mov']
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(command)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The quotation marks in the command line version are only to separate the different arguments. With a python list, they are not needed:

```
command = ['./JS/ChannelAssign5+1stereo.app/Contents/MacOS/ChannelAssign5+1stereo',
    '/Volumes/GRAID/_PREVIEWS/MASTER copy.mov']
p1 = subprocess.Popen(command)
```

Comment: Using this command I get "    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Comment: It needs the quotation marks as there is a space in the file name or path.

Comment: Did you start your script in the correct directory? And no quotes needed, the list preserves the space.

Comment: Your right, I don't get the "no such directory" now, but it still doesn't run, same result as original. Application runs, but it is not being passed the file.

Comment: @speedyrazor: you should update your question or ask a new one with this new information. Have you tried to use `subprocess.check_call` instead of `subprocess.Popen`, to wait for the child process to finish?